# Unexpected Error while Executing Simple grep Script

Tags: bash, grep, cd

I'm trying to collect a line from a series of very long files. Unfortunately, I need to extract the same line from an identically named file in 1600 distinct directories. The directory structure is like this.

Directory jan10 contains both the executed bash script, and directories named 18-109. The directories 18-109 each contain directories named 18A, 18B, ..., 18H. Inside each of these directories is the file "target.out" that we want the information from. Here is the code that I wrote to access this information:

```
for i in $(cat  ~/jan10/list.txt);
do
    cd $i
    cd *A

    grep E-SUM-OVERALL target.out | cut -c  17-24 > ../overallenergy.out

    cd ../*B
    grep E-SUM-OVERALL target.out | cut -c  17-24 >> ../overallenergy.out

    cd ../*C
    grep E-SUM-OVERALL target.out | cut -c  17-24 >> ../overallenergy.out

    cd ../*D
    grep E-SUM-OVERALL target.out | cut -c  17-24 >> ../overallenergy.out

    cd ../*E
    grep E-SUM-OVERALL target.out | cut -c  17-24 >> ../overallenergy.out

    cd ../*F
    grep E-SUM-OVERALL target.out | cut -c  17-24 >> ../overallenergy.out

    cd ../*G
    grep E-SUM-OVERALL target.out | cut -c  17-24 >> ../overallenergy.out

    cd ../*H

done
```

In this example, list.txt contains the numbers 18-109 each on a different line. An example of the "list.txt" is shown below:

```
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

Unexpectedly, this code simply won't work, it returns the error:

```
./testscript.sh: line 8: cd: 18: No such file or directory
./testscript.sh: line 11: cd: *A: No such file or directory
```

It returns this error for every numbered directory and every lettered sub-directory. Does anyone have any insight on what I've done wrong? I'll answer any questions, and I apologize again if this is unclear. The grep command by itself does work, so I imagine it's a problem with one of the "cd" commands, but I'm unsure. The code is being executed in the jan10 directory.

Comment: You don't need to `cd` around to grep files from different directories. Just include the path to the file in the grep command.

Comment: Those errors mean those directories didn't exist where you thought they would. Confirm the directories that you believe exist actually do.

Comment: can you share a portion of the content of `~/jan10/list.txt`?

Comment: From what directory did you start the script?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I know but that isn't feasible in this case because the number of directories is so large, and the directories do exist as I've said they do. I'm not sure why this method of navigation is reutrning errors, it's due to an error on my part that I cannot find. I am executing the script in the directory "jan10." So cd "$i" should put me in the first numbered directory, then "cd *A" should put me in the "$iA" directory.

Comment: wouldn't `find /base/path/of/proj/data -name target.txt | xargs simpleGrepScript.sh > overallenergy.out` where simpleGrepScript.sh is only `grep -E .. "$@"` do the job? Good luck.

Comment: @Shellter, I don't believe this automates the process. The script I've written should execute in every single subdirecctory, which is over 1000 directories.

Comment: I believe what I've outlined will search 1000s+ directories for the file `target.out` and search for 'E-SUM-OVERALL' in those files. I did not include the `| cut -c..` but editing `simpleGrepScript.sh` should be simple, (and I see that `-E` is unneeded.) . Read up about `xargs`, it is designed to manage really big lists of files/dirs. (I don't like to post answers where I can't test them at the scale of the problem). Good luck.

Comment: The problem is this will put all of the data in one output file, rather than my script that puts all the data for a single number "18A, B,C, etc." inside the directory 18. The difference is slight, but important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your requirement better (my fault), here's a more fleshed out solution.

```
prompt$ cat simpleGrepScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
if ${testMode:-true} ; then
   echo "processing file $1 into outfile ${1%/*}/../overallenergy.out" 1>&2
else
   [[ -f "$1" ]] && grep 'E-SUM-OVERALL' "$1" > ${1%/*}/../overallenergy.out || echo "no file "$1" found" 1>&2
fi
```

Run

```
prompt$ find /starting/path -name target.out | xargs /path/to/simpleGrepScript.sh
```

if the output from the testMode

```
 "processing file $1 into outfile ${1%/*}/../overallenergy.out"
```

looks OK, then change to `${testMode:-false}`.

If it doesn't look right, post the mininum error examples as a comment and I'll see if I can fix it.

If there are spaces in your path name, we'll have to circle back and add some more options to `find` and `xargs`.

IHTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
for Dir in $(cat  ~/jan10/list.txt)
do
     find "$Dir" -type f -name target.out |
     while read File
     do
          grep E-SUM-OVERALL "$File" > "${File%/*/target.out}"/overallenergy.out
     done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a shell function that, for a given directory, finds all the underlying targets and for each target outputs, on `stdout`, a suitable command.

```
% gen_greps () { 
    find $1 -name target.out | while read fname ; do 
        printf "grep E-SUM-OVERALL $fname | "
        printf "cut -c 17-24 > "
        printf "$(dirname $fname)/overallenergy.out\n"
    done
}
%
```

make a dry run

```
% gen_greps jan10
...
grep E-SUM-OVERALL jan10/29/29H/target.out | cut -c 17-24 > jan10/29/29H/overallenergy.out
...
%
```

if what we see is what we want, pass the commands to a shell for execution

```
% gen_greps jan10 | sh
%
```

That's all (?)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `for` in this way. In order for `for` to execute, it must first process the `cat` command, and if there are white spaces in the file name, the `for` will fail. Plus, it's very possible to overload your command line when executing the `for`.

Instead use a `while read` loop which is more efficient and more tolerant of file name issues:

```
while read dir
do
    ....
done < ~/jan10/list.txt
```

It is also very dangerous to use glob patters in the `cd` command because more than one file could match that pattern, and that could cause `cd` to fail.

Also, if you find yourself piping to a series of `grep`, `cut`, `sed` commands, you can usually replace that with a single `awk` command.

If all of your files you need are called `target.out` and there are no other files called `target.out` that you want to skip, you can use `find` to find the various files without changing directories to each one:

Note how much shorter and simpler the entire program is:

```
while read dir
do
    find $dir -name "target.out" -type f \
        -exec awk '/E-SUM-OVERALL/ {print substr $0, 17, 8}' {}\;
done < ~/jan10/list.txt > overallenergy.out
```

I don't have any data, so it's sort of hard to actually test this. It maybe possible that I could simply use the *field* in my `awk` rather that `substr`. Or my `substr` command could be off.